# radio_button_tag in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a query to ask. Im using radio_button_tag with rails 3.1. The issue that I come accross is that for eg : If I have ascending and descending radio buttons, only one should be selected. But in my case both the radio button tags are getting selected.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Also, if your previous questions have been answered helpfully, consider marking them as "answered" by clicking the check-mark beside the best answer. It'll make people more inclined to help in future.

Comment: Yeah thanks.. Have did it now.. Sorry and thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a guess at best, because you haven't put your code, but:

You need to ensure that your radio buttons have the same HTML `name` attribute by giving your tags the same first parameter in `radio_button_tag`. See the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag).

Comment: Thanks chowlett, that saved me from my problem.. :)

Answer (score 2):

if two radio fields has same name, one can be selected at a time!

Pass `true` to the tag you want to be selected initially. For example, if you want 'Descending' to be checked initially, write like:

```
radio_button_tag 'order', 'asc'
radio_button_tag 'order', 'desc', true
```